# Redirect Regex 2 scenarios

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm looking for some regex help for matching for some 301 redirects.

```
Match www.domain.tld only redirect to www.domain.tld/list.html
Match www.domain.tld/* redirect to subdomain.domain.tld/*, follow query strings
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to redirect the main page to `www.domain.tld/list.html` and everything else to `subdomain.domain.tld` preserving the URL path and query string

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.domain.tld/list.html [R,L]
RewriteRule .+ http://subdomain.domain.tld$0 [R,L]
```

When everything works as you expect, you can replace `[R,L]` with `[R=301,L]`, but not before.